# Custom template creates multiple H1 tags on same page

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, seo

I´m new to Joomla and started on my own template.

Using this code to get articles:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Output multiple  tags on the same page... This is, as far as I know, bad for google SEO.

Is this the normal behavior of Joomla or what should I change to avoid having multiple H1´s?

Comment: This is nothing to do with that line of code. The `<h1>` for articles derives from the following line of code: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php#L31

Comment: @Lodder Thanks! But I don´t understand why the system files would generate multiple H1 tags? also the lack of html 5 tags, like menu in <nav> tag and <article> instead of <div>

Comment: The Joomla 3.x template of pretty much rubbish and comes with so much bloat. You're definitely best off creating your own template. As for the multiple tags, is it possible that you have a Template Override for that file? Or perhaps you have the page title and article title set to "on"?

Comment: @Lodder Okay, is it allowed and possible to override the com_content parts? Just to have it display proper html5 tags... Hmm, I´m really not sure as I´m new to joomla. But I´m pretty sure I haven´t made any overrides

Comment: You can override it. Just make sure you don't edit the file mention above and you actually perform a proper override. You can find out how to do so here: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: @Lodder Awesome! thanks!... As for the multiple H1, I don´t know where to look for page title and article title on / off buttons... In Articles: Options I´ve set all buttons to off - It´s still creating multiple H1´s

Comment: Open the menu item in the admin panel and go to the "**Options**" tab. You'll see the "**Show Title**" option. Then go to the "**Page Display**" tab, where you see some more options that will render a `<h1>` tag.

Comment: Thanks!! but It dosen´t make a difference... Could it be because the page I+m displaying is showing the module featured articles and I have 3 articles as featured articles?

Comment: That could be the case, yes. In which case, you're going to want to create an override for the featured articles view and change them to H2 tags

Comment: @Lodder Thanks for all the great help. Could you make it as an answer? then I can close this question :)

Comment: It was your finding in regards to the Featured Articles, so it's your answer to post ;) You'll get my upvote

Comment: @Lodder Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue of multiple **H1** tags was introduced because the page I was viewing was showing featured articles.

Solution was to make an override of [com_contents featured file](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_content/views/featured/tmpl/default.php) by changing h1 to h2 in the file script